# Машинное обучение. Отбор признаков при построении модели

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Построил 2 модели кредитного скоринга (задача бинарной классификации) на XGBoost и RandomForest. Накидал из БД различных фичей, около 60, загрузил. Построил график значимости признаков.

1) Стоит ли усекать количество фичей, если по графику видно, что значимости они не несут, если да, то по какой линии? (график прикреплен снизу)

2) Стоит ли оставлять бинарные фичи, в которых соотношение категорий например 90 на 10% и они не входят, скажем, в первую 10ку самых значимых признаков?

3) Каким образом может повлиять на модель и конкретно на эффективность модели бустинга и случайного леса, если оставить все эти "маловлиятельные" признаки?

Или же нужно ориентироваться чисто на какие-либо метрики вроде auc-roc, gini, accuracy? Грубо говоря - убрал\добавил, посмотрел на значение метрики увеличилась\нет и опять заного..

Подскажите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция отрисовки графика:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer as Imputer
from sklearn import ensemble
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve, confusion_matrix, mean_squared_error, classification_report
import itertools
# (присутствуют лишние импорты)

def MY_plotting_feature_priority(X, model, n=3):
    importances = model.feature_importances_
    indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
    feature_names = X.columns
    d_first = X.shape[1]
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.title("Значимость признаков")
    plt.bar(range(d_first), importances[indices[:d_first]], align='center')
    plt.xticks(range(d_first), np.array(feature_names)[indices[:d_first]], rotation=90)
    plt.xlim([-1, d_first])
    best_features = indices[:n]
    best_features_names = feature_names[best_features]
    print(f'Первые {n} значимых признаков {list(best_features_names)} из {d_first} ')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

Общий ответ на ваш вопрос - все зависит от поставленных целей и стоимости ошибки.
Если вы видите, что добавдение-удаление определенного признака **на тестовой выборке** не приводит к **значимому для вас** изменению точности прогноза -  данные убираем, если приводят- оставляют. Даже если вы будете основываться на формальных метриках, в каждой из них есть порог, который вы сами вольны задать и по которому потом будете принимать решение.
Я не знаю, насколько значимо, например,  для вашего банка уменьшение ложнонегативных прогнозов на 0.0001%. Может это всего несколько тысяч рублей, что для вашего банка ничто. А вот такое же изменение в медицине - это жизнь конкретных людей. А в психологии - вообще точность порядка 10% считается отличной. 
Так что как ни крути, но окончательное решение -  всегда за вами и оно вне области формального анализа.

Comment: "..добавление-удаление определенного признака на тестовой выборке не приводит к значимому для вас изменению точности прогноза - данные убираем, если приводят- оставляют.." 

Вы имели ввиду Accuracy, с некоторым заданным порогом? 

Мне нужно, как можно меньшее количество ошибок 2 рода (False negative), как ни странно.Правильным ли решением будет, ориентироваться на метрику confusion matrix, при отбрасывании созданных признаков?

На работе просят в качестве результата предоставлять индекс Джини модели. И я не знаю на что ориентироваться, понял только то, что нужно уменьшать ошибки 2рода

Comment: Ну, вы же не будете использовать метод главных компонент для отбора признаков :-). Тем более, что у вас классификатор, а не регрессор. А дальше остается только эмпирика.  Можно если хотите,  отбирать   на основе мнимизации  FN. Тем более, что индекс Джини основанный на AUC, при расчете которой используется в том числе и FN. Так что особого противоречия - не вижу.

Comment: В общем, я повыкидывал некоторые фичи, и результат(метрика gini) на 10 блоках кросс валидации (по тренировочной части выборки) - улучшился. Так же проверил на отложенной тестовой, там gini получился равен, примерно, среднему значению на кросс валидации. Значит ли это что я все сделал правильно?)

Comment: @Ste_kd Вы всё сделали правильно. Самый надёжный способ отбора фич именно такой - выкидывать фичи по одной и смотреть метрики на кросс-валидации и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю, насколько еще актуален вопрос, но вот одно из возможных решений задачи выбора признаков именно для задач кредитного скоринга.
http://ai-news.ru/2018/12/open_source_instrument_na_python_dlya_vybora_priznakov_nejroseti.html

Comment: Спасибо за статью, почитаю